# Loading an image with a PointsMaterial in three.js

Tags: three.js

I am learning three.js (r75) and trying to load an image to use as a shader or particle.  The image appears to be loading after rendering.

I am using Ubuntu on a VM (VirtualBox, Win10 base) and running a localhost server via `Python3` and `Flask`.  I have also tried taking out all the framework stuff and tested using Python's `SimpleHTTPServer`.  3D acceleration is enabled via Chrome flag 'Override software rendering list' and all examples are working.

Having moved on from tying to get a sky box to work, I am following a tutorial on Aerotwist, https://aerotwist.com/tutorials/creating-particles-with-three-js/, to render particles - but when trying to apply the image, I get exactly the same issue as for my sky box.  The tutorial was fine up to applying the image.

All I am seeing is a blank screen (black background in my container).

Watching files load when stepping through, it appears to be loading the image (status 200) after it's finished rendering (`renderer.render(scene, camera)`) - but I could be wrong.  There are no errors displayed in Dev Tools.

I was under the impression that `THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture()` or `THREE.TextureLoader.load()` would handle the image load by default.  The image displays when mapped to a `MeshLambertMaterial`.

Appearing to be the only person with this problem (?!) - no mention in tutorials about pre-loading and not much from Google or Stack Overflow - can anyone suggest what I've done wrong or point me at something obvious, please?

Thank you! :)

This is the code.

```
; function Solar3D() {
'use strict';

var scene, renderer, camera,
    container = $('#webgl-container'),
    skyBox = null;

init();

function init() {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true
    });
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1);

    var $container = $(container);
    var containerWidth = $container.width();
    var containerHeight = $container.height();
    renderer.setSize(containerWidth, containerHeight);
    container.append(renderer.domElement);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, containerWidth / containerHeight, 1, 5000);
    camera.position.set(0, 155, 32);
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

    scene.add(particles());

    render();
}

function particles() {
    // https://aerotwist.com/tutorials/creating-particles-with-three-js/
    var particleCount = 1800,
        particles = new THREE.Geometry(),
        pMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
            color: 0xFFFFFF,
            size: 20,
            map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(
                '/app/static/img/particle.png'),
            blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
            transparent: true
        });

    for (var p = 0; p < particleCount; p++) {
        var pX = Math.random() * 500 - 250,
            pY = Math.random() * 500 - 250,
            pZ = Math.random() * 500 - 250,
            particle = new THREE.Vector3(pX, pY, pZ);
        particles.vertices.push(particle);
    }

    var particleSystem = new THREE.Points(
        particles,
        pMaterial);

    particleSystem.sortParticles = true;

    return particleSystem;
}

function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function loadTexture(path) {
    return new THREE.TextureLoader().load(path);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I guess the answer is obvious!

As I was trying to render a background, I did not want to complicate things with animation - I was not re-rendering my scene.

Rendering in an animation (or update) loop, allows the image(s) to fully load before they are actually rendered.

I added `animate();` after the `init()`, and filled it with the following

```
function animate() {
    render();
    requestAnimFrame(animate);
}
```

For completeness - I am using this animation frame:

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
    return  window.requestAnimationFrame   ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
        function( callback ){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
})();
```

Easy when you know!  Thanks to anyone who gave my question some consideration.